# Where are settings for drag-and-drop touchpad behavior?

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I use "tap to click", so when I'm performing a click-and-drag, I tap-tap-drag. If my finger reaches the edge of the touchpad and I still need to drag the cursor farther, I quickly lift and place my finger closer the center of the pad so I can continue dragging. As long as I replace my finger on the touchpad quickly enough, it doesn't treat the finger-lift as the end of the drag-and-drop action.

This has worked for me on other distros. I had NixOS w/Gnome installed on my current machine before installing Ubuntu Gnome on it, and it worked, but I can't figure out how to make it work on Ubuntu.

Is there some hidden setting I need to configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output of `synclient -l | grep -i drag`. You'll see something like this:

```
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
```

I think `LockedDragTimeout` is the setting you want. To change it temporarily, run `synclient LockedDragTimeout=value`. Once you are happy with the value, add the command to startup applications.

Comment: It turns out my system doesn't have `synclient`, because gnome is using libinput rather than synaptics. The feature I was looking for is "drag lock", and it's settable via xinput. Now I just need to figure out how to store it's configuration rather than manually setting it each time my graphical shell starts.

Comment: Even weirder, after finding that my system was using libinput rather than synaptics, I set the appropriate libinput settings and got drag-lock to work, but after a reboot, I find that my system is now using synaptics rather than libinput. I have no idea what's going on :O

Answer (score 1):

To expand on mikewhatever's answer:

```
synclient TapAndDragGesture=1 LockedDrags=1 LockedDragTimeout=200
```

should do the trick temporarily.  Specifically, you need the `LockedDrags=1` option to enable them.

- `TapAndDragGesture=1` ensures that tap-and-drag gestures are enabled (just in case).
- `LockedDrags=1` enables locked drags (locks drag-and-drop until you tap again or a timeout happens).
- `LockedDragTimeout=200` lowers the locked drag timeout from 5000 ms (default) to 200.  If left at 5000, drag-and-drop will be locked until you tap on the touchpad (or wait 5 seconds).

For more info, run `man synaptics`.  For a list of available options and their current values, run `synclient -l`.  Once you have figured out your favorite settings, add them to a startup script as mikewhatever suggests.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all remove synaptics by the command:

**sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics**

2. Then do the following :

Go to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/**40-libinput.conf** (it is a file edit with text editor in root mode) and paste the following:

**Option "TappingDragLock" "1"**

at here in the Touchpad Section

Section "InputClass"
Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Driver "libinput"
Option "TappingDragLock" "1"
EndSection

Thank You