# Drag Lock not working on fresh 20.04 install

Tags: touchpad, 20.04, xinput, drag-and-drop, libinput

This is a Dell Inspiron 15 7559 from 2016 which came preinstalled with Ubuntu at the time. I had later been running 16.04 for the past 4 years without a problem.

Yesterday, I did a fresh install (*wiped out the disk*) with 20.04 (*on legacy bios because uefi caused issues with audio*) only to find out that I cannot get drag lock to work.

```
xinput list
```

typically gives me (both on 16.04 and 20.04)

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1010:00 04F3:3012 Mouse               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1010:00 04F3:3012 Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and the id's across the two touchpad devices seem to occasionally change, so I use the full names of th two devices to set properties on them.

On 16.04, I used to run the following on login to enable drag lock

```
xinput --set-prop "ELAN1010:00 04F3:3012 Touchpad" "Synaptics Locked Drags" 1
xinput --set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "Synaptics Locked Drags" 1
```

These two commands error out as it turns out the property names have changed from synaptics to libinput. Running `xinput --list-props` on either one gives me the following

```
Device 'ELAN1010:00 04F3:3012 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (197):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (199): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (349): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (350): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (351):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (352):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (353):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (354):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (355):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (356):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (333):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (334):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (357):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (358):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (335):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (336):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (337):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (359): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (360):    0, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (361):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (362):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (363):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (340): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (341): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (345): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (346): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (318): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (319):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (320):    0, 0
    Device Node (321):  "/dev/input/event12"
    Device Product ID (322):    1267, 12306
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (347):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (348):   1
```

and

```
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (197):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (199): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (349): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (350): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (351):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (352):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (353):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (354):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (355):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (356):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (333):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (334):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (357):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (358):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (335):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (336):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (337):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (359): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (360):    0, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (361):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (362):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (363):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (340): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (341): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (345): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (346): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (318): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (319):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (320):    0, 0
    Device Node (321):  "/dev/input/event7"
    Device Product ID (322):    2, 14
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (347):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (348):   1
```

Therefore I naturally tried the following

```
xinput --set-prop "ELAN1010:00 04F3:3012 Touchpad" "libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled" 1
xinput --set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled" 1
```

which succeed in setting the properties but the behavior of the touchpad does not change.

Finally, I've also updated gnome settings and ensure that

gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-and-drag

gives me

true

So far I am unable to make this work.

PS: I am using Xorg as

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

outputs

```
x11
```

PPS: The contents of `/proc/bus/input/devices` are as follows for the relevant devices

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=000e Version=0000
N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event7 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e420 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=661800011000003

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=3012 Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN1010:00 04F3:3012 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN1010:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN1010:00/0018:04F3:3012.0001/input/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event12 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

PPPS: There is no `/etc/x11/xorg.conf` or `/etc/x11/xorg.conf.d/` present on my drive.

PPPPS: There is some information about this in the [libinput man pages](https://www.mankier.com/4/libinput#Button_Drag_Lock) but I honestly don't understand the steps needed to make it work

**EDIT**
Based on the comment from @Hi-Angel libinput does support drag lock but has a default and unconfigurable 300ms timeout to it, so here's some updates that can help move in that direction for a solution:

- [Another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964597/where-are-settings-for-drag-and-drop-touchpad-behavior) suggests while synclient supports configurable timeouts (defaulting to 5000, libinput does not)
- A [reported issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/issues/319) reveals libinput maintainers don't seem to immediately grasp the utility of this
- [A PR](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/merge_requests/258/diffs) and [another one](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-input-libinput/-/merge_requests/6) have been abandoned trying to get this in

I'm unfamiliar with the inner workings of libinput and C programming in general, do you think there's a way that I can get this working on my computer _(without having to rebuild a custom, local version of libinput and having to maintain it forever?) _

Comment: The docs you referred to is about button lock, it's not something you're interested in. Regarding the problem: by any chance, could that be that what actually happens is libinput drag-lock timeout is just smaller than it was on synaptics? I just tested: for me on libinput 1.15.5 drag-lock works. The time after which lock gets released if you didn't re-tap is about 1 second, which seems to be small enough to not notice the effect unless you know what to look for. I don't know how long the timeout was on synaptics

Comment: Thank you, I missed that detail, yet I was kind of hoping that was relevant because the more relevant options I tried did not work. About timeout, well, wow you are absolutely correct! The timeout seems to be a couple hundred milliseconds, though. I don't see that option in the list. Do you know how I can update it? And if you do, would you mind putting that up as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: @Hi-Angel I've edited the question with some findings on your pointer. Do you mind checking that information I provided at the end of the quesion in the EDIT section? Thank you!

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy I am facing the same issue. Have you been able to find a workaround?

Comment: @rajeevmaash check out the answer below, it works but it times out. It is not sticky forever like it used to be before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per comments, drag lock does actually work, but it is easy to miss because the drag timeout *(i.e. time for which "drag" works after you lifted a finger from the touchpad but before you put it back)* is very small, it is 300 ms. Synaptics had it 5 sec by default.

The reason it is so small is to be unobtrusive. Though there probably may be a value in increasing it up to infinity for accessibility reasons.

ATM there's not easy way to change timeout. As a hack, one can change [the timeout value on this line](https://github.com/wayland-project/libinput/blob/bd7b91065b138760201e8454c4559f2023f3cde1/src/evdev-mt-touchpad-tap.c#L33) and rebuild libinput from sources.

However, as rightfully noted by the OP, there is an [open MR](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/merge_requests/258) to make the timeout configurable. Which was abandoned by the author as well as [the corresponding issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/issues/319). But it's easy to see that the maintainer is open to the idea. You may try to join the discussion and if your reasoning turns out to be convincing enough, it should be trivial to rebase and merge that already existing MR.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for the touchpad.

Install synaptics with `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`
, restart.

Then `synclient LockedDrags=1` and it should work.

Still to do: same for mouse and make change permanent across sessions.  You will explain us how to do.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't quite agree that it is a solution. It is a workaround that deviates the stock ubuntu 20.04 from its preferred and supported choice of driver. I prefer remaining a desktop user and get a proper desktop experience rather than having to subscribe to the "linux is infinitely customizable" rhetoric, which I do appreciate, but rather not "have to" resort to.