# How to activate touchpad Drag Lock on Wayland on 20.10?

Tags: touchpad, wayland, drag-and-drop, 20.10

I'd like some leeway to reposition my finger during a drag-and-drop with my touchpad, but [the solutions I find](https://askubuntu.com/q/964597/428527) all mention either `synclient` which is not installed by default and I assume is not relevant in stock Ubuntu, or `xinput` which complains when called against Xwayland.

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
```

What would be the supported way of enabling this feature when using Wayland? Or is there an alternative solution to the drag-and-drop problem that I'm unaware about? For instance, in macOS I would use three finger dragging (which works fantastically well) on the same hardware.